# Throwing doubles in Computer Backgammon

Tags: probability

I am playing a computer game of Backgammon. I believe that the programme is biased towards the computer character. 
Here is the basis for my suspicion: 
I have played 223 games so far:
Here are my statistics: Thrown 877 doubles out of 5549 throws comprising
              Double ones 144
              Double twos 149
              Double threes 160
              Double fours 157
              Double fives 134
              Double sixes 133
The statistics for the computer character (Bill) are 966 doubles out of 5553 throws comprising
              Double ones 163
              Double twos 154
              Double threes 164
              Double fours 153
              Double fives 160
              Double sixes 172
Are my suspicions real in that the computer is favouring the character Bill?

Comment: This is hard to read.  Perhaps it would help if you organized your data into a table instead of just a run on sentence.

Comment: You should expect about one in every six throws to be a double of something.  This will follow a binomial distribution with mean $np$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$ where $n$ is the number of throws and $p$ is $\frac{1}{6}$ in this case.  In 5553 throws, we should have expected about $926$ of them to be doubles, plus or minus $50$ or so.  So, Bill's statistics are right in line with what we should expect.  Slightly on the high side, but not unreasonably so by any means.

Comment: Thank you for that. So my number of expected doubles would be 925 (to nearest whole number) plus or minus 50 gives 875. So Bill is the lucky one to get the higher expectation and I am unlucky to get the lower expectation. However, I am beating him just with the number of won games, thus making me the better player!